# Joomla 3 module repeated fields

Tags: xml, joomla

im doing a custom module bear with me as its my first time to create my own module on joomla 3, so far on .xml file my code is ridiculously long but well its working properly, i have 50 fields lol and this is how i declared it

```
<fieldset name="branches" label="MOD_BRANCH" description="MOD_BRANCH_DESCRIPTION">  
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer1" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #1 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #1" name="branch_name1" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #1" name="branch_tel1" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr2" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer2" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #2 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #2" name="branch_name2" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #2" name="branch_tel2" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr3" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer3" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #3 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #3" name="branch_name3" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #3" name="branch_tel3" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr4" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer4" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #4 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #4" name="branch_name4" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #4" name="branch_tel4" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr5" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer5" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #5 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #5" name="branch_name5" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #5" name="branch_tel5" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr6" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer6" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #6 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #6" name="branch_name6" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #6" name="branch_tel6" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr7" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer7" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #7 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #7" name="branch_name7" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #7" name="branch_tel7" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr8" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer8" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #8 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #8" name="branch_name8" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #8" name="branch_tel8" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr9" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer9" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #9 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #9" name="branch_name9" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #9" name="branch_tel9" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr10" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer10" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #10 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #10" name="branch_name10" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #10" name="branch_tel10" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr11" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer11" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #11 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #11" name="branch_name11" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #11" name="branch_tel11" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr12" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer12" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #12 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #12" name="branch_name12" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #12" name="branch_tel12" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr13" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer13" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #13 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #13" name="branch_name13" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #13" name="branch_tel13" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr14" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer14" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #14 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #14" name="branch_name14" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #14" name="branch_tel14" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr15" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer15" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #15 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #15" name="branch_name15" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #15" name="branch_tel15" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr16" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer16" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #16 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #16" name="branch_name16" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #16" name="branch_tel16" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr17" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer17" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #17 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #17" name="branch_name17" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #17" name="branch_tel17" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr18" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer18" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #18 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #18" name="branch_name18" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #18" name="branch_tel18" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr19" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer19" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #19 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #19" name="branch_name19" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #19" name="branch_tel19" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr20" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer20" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #20 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #20" name="branch_name20" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #20" name="branch_tel20" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr21" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer21" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #21 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #21" name="branch_name21" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #21" name="branch_tel21" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr22" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer22" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #22 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #22" name="branch_name22" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #22" name="branch_tel22" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr23" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer23" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #23 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #23" name="branch_name23" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #23" name="branch_tel23" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr24" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer24" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #24 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #24" name="branch_name24" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #24" name="branch_tel24" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr25" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer25" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #25 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #25" name="branch_name25" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #25" name="branch_tel25" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr26" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer26" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #26 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #26" name="branch_name26" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #26" name="branch_tel26" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr27" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer27" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #27 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #27" name="branch_name27" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #27" name="branch_tel27" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr28" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer28" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #28 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #28" name="branch_name28" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #28" name="branch_tel28" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr29" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer29" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #29 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #29" name="branch_name29" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #29" name="branch_tel29" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr30" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer30" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #30 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #30" name="branch_name30" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #30" name="branch_tel30" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr31" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer31" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #31 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #31" name="branch_name31" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #31" name="branch_tel31" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr32" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer32" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #32 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #32" name="branch_name32" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #32" name="branch_tel32" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr33" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer33" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #33 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #33" name="branch_name33" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #33" name="branch_tel33" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr34" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer34" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #34 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #34" name="branch_name34" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #34" name="branch_tel34" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr35" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer35" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #35 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #35" name="branch_name35" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #35" name="branch_tel35" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr36" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer36" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #36 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #36" name="branch_name36" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #36" name="branch_tel36" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr37" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer37" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #37 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #37" name="branch_name37" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #37" name="branch_tel37" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr38" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer38" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #38 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #38" name="branch_name38" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #38" name="branch_tel38" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr39" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer39" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #39 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #39" name="branch_name39" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #39" name="branch_tel39" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr40" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer40" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #40 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #40" name="branch_name40" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #40" name="branch_tel40" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr41" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer41" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #41 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #41" name="branch_name41" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #41" name="branch_tel41" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr42" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer42" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #42 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #42" name="branch_name42" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #42" name="branch_tel42" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr43" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer43" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #43 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #43" name="branch_name43" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #43" name="branch_tel43" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr44" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer44" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #44 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #44" name="branch_name44" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #44" name="branch_tel44" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr45" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer45" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #45 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #45" name="branch_name45" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #45" name="branch_tel45" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr46" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer46" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #46 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #46" name="branch_name46" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #46" name="branch_tel46" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr47" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer47" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #47 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #47" name="branch_name47" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #47" name="branch_tel47" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr48" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer48" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #48 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #48" name="branch_name48" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #48" name="branch_tel48" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr49" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer49" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #49 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #49" name="branch_name49" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #49" name="branch_tel49" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacerhr50" hr="true" />
<field type="spacer" name="myspacer50" class="text" label="&lt;b&gt;Branch #50 Info&lt;/b&gt;" />
<field type="text" label="Branch / Area #50" name="branch_name50" description="MOD_BRANCH_NAME_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />
<field type="text" label="Tel No. for #50" name="branch_tel50" description="MOD_BRANCH_TEL_DESCRIPTION" default="" class="" size="32" maxlength="32" filter="" />           
            </fieldset>
```

please dont laugh at me im not a professional programmer, as you may notice to recognize which is which i only added number on each name tags lol, is there anyway that i can make this short? as i said its working well its just that it looks so unprofessional. hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine and that is certainly the simplest way to do it.  Unless you need the flexibility of adding more than 50, deleting ones in the middle and reordering then I would stick with what you have.

Alternatively you could use a subform field (eg. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17134/new-sub-form-field-function-in-joomla-3-6) which requires several more files and has a few gotchas in it.  But this is what you want if you want to have add, delete and reorder.

Other options like a custom field or js based interface are more complicated than the above.

Also note that Joomla has its own stack exchange https://joomla.stackexchange.com which is much better for joomla questions.